# Criar função que receba um XML no Servidor SOAP (delphi)

Tags: delphi, web-service, soap

Bom dia.
Lendo vários arquivo,tutoriais, etc na net, consegui entender e desenvolver um servidor SOAP (Delphi 7 e Tokyo).
Criei varias funções para receber valores e retornar resposta..
Criei um cliente (Delphi 7 e Tokyo) e consegui consumir sem nenhum mistério TODAS as funções do servidor SOAP através da importação do WSDL que o servidor SOAP disponibiliza.
Mas Todas as funções que desenvolvi no servidor SOAP recebem parâmetros do tipo String ou inteiro. 
Gostaria de fazer uma função no SERVIDOR SOAP que recebesse um XML, contudo não encontro nenhum artigo que me ajude a sanar essa necessidade.
Algum dos senhores poderia me indicar uma direção, ou informar algo que eu possa ler para ficar mais esclarecido??
Desculpem se escrevi algo fora do contexto do SERVIDOR SOAP, mas estou iniciando nesse estranho mundo SOAP agora e não conheço ainda as palavras certas para descrever minha necessidade.
Caso não tenha sido claro o bastante, por favor sinalizem ou peçam mais informações que tentarei esclarecer com outras palavras.

Comment: Ricardo, porque ao invés de receber um XML, você não cria uma classe que sirva como model, com atributos e sub-classes e serializa ela na saída do webservice. Acredito que possa ser mais simples de manipular a informação.

Comment: Boa tarde @Andre Mesquita. Na realidade essa necessidade especifica deve-se ao fato de um cliente já TER um xml pronto que ele envia através do sistema dele.  Ele aperta o botão lá no sistema dele e envia o arquivo. A única coisa que ele pode alterar e para onde vai o arquivo. Ele já tem toda uma estrutura do lado dele.  Me compreende?  E pelo pouco conhecimento que tenho no momento, não entendi muito bem sua sugestão.. :(

Comment: Entendi o seu caso. Dá uma olhada nessa thread do SO que pode te ajudar a receber o XML e carregar diretamente no objeto. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15688157/2788478)

Comment: Boa noite @Andre MEsquita. Irei dar uma olhada no link que tu menciona. Obrigado pela atenção :)